# The parent HLS manifest could not be parsed. - error code 232600

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwplayer, aws-amplify, obs

I am using amazon web service. I created to web app using amply framework to make live stream web app. In here I used 3rd party software OBS to live stream. I am using JW player to view my live stream video. So I copied URL from my created web application and paste into JW player. Unfortunately, I always got below error.

> This video file cannot be played.(Error Code: 232600)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/633p8.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide an example of the HLS manifest the URL responds with?

Comment: Here I attached image